# How can I implement a radio button in OSX, Xcode 8, Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I am trying to implement a radio button in OSX, Xcode 8, Swift 3. I could do this in past iterations of Xcode with a radio button group. I *believe* that there should be a way to group radio buttons in Xcode so that their selection is exclusive, but I can't figure out how. Could someone please explain how to do this now?

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/) explains that

> An NSButton configured as a radio button (with the -buttonType set to
>   NSRadioButton), will now operate in a radio button group for
>   applications linked on 10.8 and later. To have the button work in a
>   radio group, use the same -action for each NSButton instance, and have
>   the same superview for each button. When these conditions are met,
>   checking one button (by changing the -state to 1), will uncheck all
>   other buttons (by setting their -state to 0).

...but I haven't been able in the Interface  Builder to figure out how to assign the same action for each NSButton instance. I drag from a second button to  an action in the Xcode IDE, and it doesn't seem to be able to select the same action. Can someone explain the correct process?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there might be a bug in the IDE — it gets confused if the action has a parameter of type `Any`. You can work around it by modifying the action method to accept a `NSButton` sender explicitly:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: That's super useful--it took a minute until I identified in the gif that you graciously provided that what you need to connect to is "First Responder". Thanks!

Comment: What I was connecting to is actually the App Delegate object. First Responder might work too, depending how your responder chain is set up. But I think it's pretty common to use the view controller object (if you have one, that is — they're more common on iOS, but nowadays the macOS equivalent NSViewController is more full-featured than it used to be).